# How to convert jar files into exe & rpm

Tags: java, installation

I have the following jar files for my app:

DesktopApplication1.jar

Plus , i have used the some extra API's for my app , like jsoup, jexcelapi etc. There are about 7 api's in the lib folder.

How to make a EXE file & RPM file out of all these jar files?

P.S. I am a first timer. So take that into consideration.also, I have used Netbeans 6.8. So the main API is in \dist folder. And the API used is in \dist\lib folder.

thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you sure you need .exe? What is the point when java is platform independent? Maybe self-executable jar would be sufficient for you?

Comment: How do i make self-executable jar

Comment: For another solution You can use Java Service Wrapper. So you can start, stop, restart application using wrapper binary. such as `projectapp/bin/app start` `projectapp/bin/app stop` `projectapp/bin/app restart`
http://adisembiring.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/running-java-applications-as-a-linux-service/#more-280

Comment: Basically you need a manifest specifying main class and dependencies. Here is some tutorial on it: http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/createjar.html

Comment: I opened my Manifest.mf file to add the main class. But the file has the following content:  Manifest-Version: 1.0
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build your JAR with [fatJar](http://fjep.sourceforge.net/) to include all the dependencies in it, and then make it executable with your favorite tool (I use [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/))

RPM is little bit different, since it is not executable, but package format. There are lots of tutorials, how you build it up.

Comment: On top: exes produced with Launch4j still runnable with java -jar myprog.exe on every platform.

Answer (score 5):

use [jsmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/) to make exe from jar

Comment: JSmooth is really cool, it worked right from the start and the GUI is easy to understand. Launch4j is buggy. It does not work where JSmooth works.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a BAT file a file with .bat(For windows) extension

Just open notepad and write the following text

```
java -jar DesktopApplication1.jar
```

Save the file as filename.bat(the **.bat** extension is important)

Place the .jar and .bat files together and just double click the .bat file every time you need to run the jar...

If you don't want to keep both together then give the absolute path of the jar in the **.bat** file

```
java -jar AbsolutePath/DesktopApplication1.jar
```

For a linux machine make a file with (**.sh**) extension rest of the procedure is same...

Comment: @downvoter: this was in reply of sunandan's comment that said he wanted to make the jar self execute...

Answer (score 0):

Try [InstallJammer](http://www.installjammer.com/download). It provides what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Deploy the app. with [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS Can make it easy to add other Jars to the apps. run-time class-path, avoiding the common problem with fat jar of violating the API's distribution license (when it says WTE 'you are allowed to distribute this in *unaltered* form..') and can provide the further benefit of only downloading the parts that the user requires (when the user requires them).

JWS has many other cool features like desktop integration (menu bars, start menu item), splash screens, automatic updates, support by the owners of Java, and compatibility with any platform for which Java is available.

Answer (score 0):

For creating .exe to run on Windows:

1. Download launch4j from http://launch4j.sourceforge.net.
2. build wrapper .exe through launch4j.
3. Download innoSetup from http://www.jrsoftware.org/isdl.php.
4. Build .exe as installer, the setup file, for user to download and install.
5. Install rpm for linux:
   If your application used other native libraries, you need to download and install Linux native libraries. This is how we build rpm for our app.